# Attaching csv file to email in django

Tags: python, django

I need to create a  mail that should have a csv file as an attachment. How do I attach a csv file to a mail in django?

Answer (score 9):

To attach files to emails sent by django, you'll have to create an [`EmailMessage`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects) instance and attach the file using the `.attach()` method.

For example, assuming you have the CSV content in `csv_data`:

```
email = EmailMessage('Subject', 'email body', 'from@mail.com', ['to@mail.com'])
email.attach('name.csv', csv_data, 'text/csv')
email.send()
```

Or, if the CSV data is in a file, you can use:

```
email.attach_file('/full/path/to/file.csv')
```

For more information on sending emails, see [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/).